# What is the largest integer n such that (2n+15)(n+1) and n(n+5) have the same prime divisors (The exponents on these prime divisors don't matter)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I started this problem by noting that $n$ and $n+1$ are always relatively prime. (other than when n=1...) This means that $n+1$ and $n+5$ share factors, and that $n$ and $2n+15$ share factors. But I'm not sure if this is right.

Comment: Well, n+1 and n can't share the factors, so n+1 and n+5 must share factors

Comment: Not following your argument.  Yes, $\gcd (n,n+1)=1$.  But that only tells you that $(n+1)$ and $(n+5)$ have the same prime divisors, not that one divides the other.

Comment: oops, that's what I meant ;-;

Comment: Note, then, that if $p$ divides both $n+1$ and $n+5$ that $p$ must divide $4$.

Comment: or a multiple of 2. right?

Comment: Well, seems to me that means $p$ must be $2$, since $p$ is prime.  What's the source of this problem?  Do you know any $n$ which work?

Comment: Not sure if any work, there may be only 1 solution

Comment: Sorry, think I'm going too fast.  knowing That $\gcd (n,n+1)=1$ just implies that any $p$ which divides $n+1$ also divides $n+5$ (not the other way round, necessarily).  Thus $n+1$ must be a power of $2$, but you don't know about $n+5$ just from this.

Comment: I think 15 does work, though

Comment: I'm going through to see what n are multiples of 5 and n+1 is in the form of 2^k

Comment: It also follows from $\gcd (n,n+1)=1$ that any prime which divides $n$ divides $2n+15$ which in turn implies it divides $15$.  Thus $n=3^a5^b$ and $n+1=2^c$.

Comment: So does that make 15 as n?

Comment: (or the biggest possible $n$)

Comment: I don't see that yet.